# Is there a way to find a specific number in a float? like the find() method for a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, integer

I am trying to check in a number of type float if there is a specific digit.
If it was a string I would use the method find(), and I thought about converting the number first to a string, then use find() and then reconvert it. 
But it isn't productive. Is there a special method or faster way of doing it?

Thank you for the help

Comment: What does "not productive" mean? Also, what is the purpose overall because floating point numbers suffer from error after a certain number of digits

Comment: You don't need to "reconvert it". `is '2' in str(12345.6789)` but it might not work the way you expect due to floating point number. Maybe consider multiplying and using ints instead.

Comment: Regular expression `re.findall("\d+\.\d+", "Current Level: 13.4 db.")` will give you `['13.4']`.

Comment: If you need to process a floating point number on the basis of its decimal representation, you should treat is as a string from the beginning and only after you have done that processing convert it to float. For example, if you have a float value given by the user, read it as a string, validate it's a float (with a regex or checking that converting to float doesn't file) but keep it as a string, do the digit-related processing, then convert it to float. If you go from float to string and back you are likely to find unexpected results for some values.

Comment: the last few digits of a floating point number in decimal form may be pretty arbitrary due to the limited precision of the type. So I'd suggest using `format` to limit the number of decimal places (and avoid scientific notation, assuming you don't want to look for your digit in an exponent, e.g. `'3' in str(6.02e23)`). Are you sure searching for a specific digit is what you want, not some more mathematical property?

Comment: Depending on the precision of the number in question, you may need to use the `Decimal` library before doing any string operations to avoid precision issues